# Microsoft Threat Modeling tool: how to avoid Spoofing of Destination Data Store

Tags: spoofing, threat-modeling, sdl

I have a threat model with a Cloud Storage entity an Managed Application which accesses it. Here is the diagram:

[image: simple threat model]

The Microsoft Threat Modeling Tool says in the report that:

> Cloud Storage may be spoofed by an attacker and this may lead to data being written to the attacker's target instead of Cloud Storage. Consider using a standard authentication mechanism to identify the destination data store.

Why is that? In an HTTPS connection the destination is always authenticated (see element properties) What setting should I modify to get rid of this threat?

EDIT: here are all the properties of the two elements:
[image: Managed application properties]
[image: Cloud storage properties]

Comment: It looks like you've selected the channel which is marked as authenticated, but the warning is coming from the Cloud Storage element. The CS element probably has it's own authenticated flag.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately it has no authenticated flag. Question updated with all properties for all elements.

Comment: I just tried it and it looks like it's one of the required reviews. This sort of makes sense because its a generic storage type (you say HTTPS, yet its connecting to SQL), so you must explicitly define how its mitigated in the threat notes.

Comment: Which you do by setting Status = Mitigated.

Comment: Thx again. Same thing happens btw if I use "Binary" instead of "HTTPS", even if I set both source and destination to authenticated.